# Angular 2 app structure

Tags: angular

Angular 2 is pretty new to me and I need support to structure a project. I'm not sure what parts of the project to include in the Angular 2 app. The fist part of the app is a pure html welcome page with just a little interaction (user can also read about the business and so on). I want this page to load quickly since its the first impression for the user. This page have a simple form with 4 options and a button to move in to the real app and the app display data depending on the short form. Then the user can start to explore the data, sort and so on. This is where I see use of Angular. So the question is, should the welcome page be a part of the Angular app or should it be pure html delivered by the server (with some css and maybe jquery)? And the data delivered to the url or by cookie?

There is also an admin panel for this system.  Should that be in the same Angular app or should it be a different one? And how to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The welcome page definitely could be part of your angular app, just load the app and then implement the logic to control when to show it or not, maybe using a modal popup (you may like to consider [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) or [PrimeNG](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/) for this).

The admin module also can be included in the same app, you just have to validate against the user roles/permissions when to show it accessible. There's a menu module in PrimeNG that you can conditionally load options too.